# Python asyncio within Multiprocessing. One event loop per process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am writing a function for my team that will download some data from the cloud. The function itself is a regular python function but under the hood, it uses asyncio. So, I create an event loop with in my function and have async coroutines do the downloading concurrently. After the data is downloaded, I process it and return the results.

My function works as expected when I call it from any other Python function. But, when I try to parallelize it using multiprocessing, I am occasionally seeing some IOErrors.

I tried to search for an example on how to achieve this but I couldn't find any. I only see recommendations to use a `concurrent.futures` and have the event loop's `run_in_executor` do the parallelization. That is not an options for me because, I want to hide all the async stuff from my team and just provide them this simple Python function that they can call from their code (possibly in multiprocessing). I have seen arguments online for why this is a bad idea, and why I shouldn't conceal the async stuff, but in my case, my team aren't savvy programmers. They would never use (or bother to understand) asyncio and so a simple python function is what works best for us.

Lastly, here is a pseudo example that shows what I am trying to do:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from typing import List

async def _async_fetch_data(symbol: str) -> bytes:
    '''
    Download stock data for given symbol from yahoo finance.
    '''

    async with asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(50), aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            url = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?symbol={symbol}&period1=0&period2=9999999999&interval=1d'

            async with session.get(url) as response:
                return await response.read()
        except:
            return None

def fetch_data(symbols: List[str]) -> List[bytes]:
    ''' 
    Gateway function that wraps the under the hood async stuff 
    '''

    coroutine_list = [_async_fetch_data(x) for x in symbols]
    if len(coroutine_list) == 0:
        return []

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    data = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(coroutine_list))[0]
    loop.close()
    return [d.result() for d in data if d.result() is not None]
```

This works alright if I run it as

```
>>> data = fetch_data(['AAPL', 'GOOG'])
```

But I am afraid if it will run alright when I do

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool as ProcessPool
>>> with ProcessPool(2) as pool:
        data = [j for i in pool.map(fetch_data, [['AAPL', 'GOOG'], ['AMZN', 'MSFT']]) for j in i]
```

I am seeing occasional IOErrors but I cannot reproduce them and I am not sure if it is because I am mixing asyncio with multiprocessing or because of something else.

Comment: Can you post a traceback?

Comment: a good guess: yahoo is throttling your connection or you are reaching the network line rate speed.

Comment: I will this time I get those errors. Like an idiot, I forgot to save the error messages. Actually, the yahoo is a pseudo example. My real project is downloading the data from our cloud storage. Also, please note that the part that deals with yahoo here (same in my real project) is in a try/except block. My real intention with this question is to get a confirmation that what I am doing there is not a big no no. Because it is very strange that I couldn't find a single example online that does the above.

Comment: I don't see anything that would prevent you from doing that unless the network/server limitation. btw, cloud services are likely to be throttled: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html